# Wired and wireless network using powerline extender

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm not an expert on networks and hardware setup so you will have to excuse my ignorance :-)

I have a wired router (ZyXEL VMG1312-B10A) and a wifi-router (TP-LINK AC1750) connected in my appartment. The wired router is in bridged routing mode so the signal is relayed to the wireless router which has been confirmed by my ISP. This setup is working fine.

I recently bought several TP-LINK AV500 powerline extenders in order to wire up my PS3 which is located far away from both routers.
The wired router has 4 ports and my question is whether it is possible to use the available ports on that router for my other devices (NAS, SONOS bridge etc.) and also broadcast a wireless signal from the other router via the powerline extenders?

Comment: Is the "regular router" doing bridged routing or just creating a wireless bridge? Lack of detail makes this hard to answer.

Comment: Hi Linef4ult I will have to ask my network supplier what kind of routing it is and I'll post the answer here

Comment: Knowing the model of your devices would help us help you. Could you [edit] your question please?

Comment: I'm really sorry about the lack of activity on this thread but for some reason superuser is not displayed in my list of stack communities so I forgot all about this. I'll get the info and modify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the ports. The power line extenders convert wired Ethernet (the ports on your router) to run over the power lines of your house and back to Ethernet. Simply plug one power line adapter near your router and connect an Ethernet cable to the adapter and your router.  Then use a power line adapter and Ethernet cable to your PlayStation. And you can add as many power line adapter to devices as necessary. You only need one adapter connected to the router.

The wireless aspect of the routers will not be affected in any way by the power line adapters. They simply provide a wired connection where there are no wires. In other words, if there is an Ethernet port, you can use the power line adapters.  All my other devices, such as PCs, laptops, anything that has an Ethernet port are all connected by power line. While it still used an Ethernet cable, I can use a short one, as there is always a power outlet nearby. This allows me to not have to run long Ethernet cables around the house.

I stopped using WiFi, as the power line adapters provide much faster speeds than my wireless router. I have my smart TV, consoles, and media center hooked up to a switch which is then connected to the router via power line adapter. This was a much faster and more consistent connection than WiFi for me.